# Simple question about mathmode

Tags: math-mode, indexing

Good morning,

I would like to write a mathematical equation like:

```
$F_{i}$
```

but I want to shift down the letter i more than the effect of the command $_$.

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix: use an empty superscript along with the subscript. Compare the following.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$F_{i} F^{}_{i}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Lowering the subscript gives the optical illusion that it also shifted to the right, to make this less obvious, I agree on the suggestion by @Bernard to use `\mkern-1.5mu`. See a comparison `$F^{}_{i}$` vs. `$F^{}_{\mkern-1.5mu i}$`:

[image]

Comment: +1. In addition, do suggest to "snug up" the subscript term to the letter `F`, by writing `$F^{}_{\!i}$`.

Comment: @Mico: Perhaps `-3mu` is too much. `\mkern -1.5mu` (or `-1mu`) would be preferable, don't you think?

Comment: @AboAmmar Thank you for your answer. Could you tell please how to make a long bar in math mode. Usually I use \bar{x} but the bar is long enough. Thank you

Comment: @Bernard - To my eyes, `\mkern-3mu` is about right for the `F`-`i` combination; however, as always, there's no arguing about tastes, right? :-) For sure, though, `F_{\mkern-1.5mu i}^{}` is preferable to `F^{}_{i}`.

Comment: @AH -- Use `\overline{x}`, it is wider.

Comment: @Mico: Non est disputandum indeed (oops… enim) :o)